# libswresample in recent Ubuntu version?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am wondering which package covers libswresample of a recent Ubuntu version (and maybe also earlier ones and hopefully also Debian). Is it covered at all?

If not, what other lib should I use to resample the audio? Best would be to have it working just everywhere, i.e. the lib be available everywhere.

Or maybe I just distribute libswresample along with my project and statically link to it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu currently use the "libav" fork of FFMPEG. This fork has a library called libavresample, that is very similar to libswresample but not compatible. Unfortunately Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't seem to include this library, either. It remains to be seen if the Debian FFMPEG maintainer will keep using that fork, or if they'll switch back to original FFMPEG that contains libswresample as well as (for full compatibility) libavresample. http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/16946/35690/

Meanwhile your best bet is to remove all libav packages from your system and use FFMPEG packages from https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg or if you want bleeding edge, build it from source.

The drawback is that some Debian software might depend on libav. Having both libraries installed on the same system, in different locations, might be possible (I even managed to use both in the same program) but it is prone to cause problems because they use identically named files and symbols.

Comment: Note that there is currently the discussion about reintroducing FFmpeg to Debian, see e.g. [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8099003).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found anything (comment, post, ...) answering this explicitly. Nor have I found such package (esp. not in the official repo). So, to answer the question: There is no such package.

My solution right now was to compile FFmpeg just manually. `./configure && make && sudo make install` mostly works. This includes libswresample. `--enable-shared` was also useful, if you need that (otherwise only static libs).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently most of the answers are outdated. The current Ubuntu 20.04 has libswresample in the **libswresample3** and **libswresample-dev** packages.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to wake an old question but Ubuntu 14.04 will likely bring libavresample back.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libavresample1

Comment: The question was about libswresample, not libavresample.

Comment: Converting code between the two versions is trivial (I've done it).  But without any of them resampling is not possible.  Ubuntu uses libav.org not ffmpeg.  libswresample is from ffmpeg, libavresample is from libav.org.  But why were neither included?